# 403 Error when authenticating organizational users with Microsoft Graph in PHP

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have got an error when following this Microsoft [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/php). This is the error I'm getting [pic of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXCKK.png)

I only get this error when I try to login with my organizational AD account, however when I log in with my personal Microsoft account all work as expected.

I'm new to both Microsoft Graph and Larvel I'm not 100% sure what is causing the issue, but I believe that it might have something to do with permissions for the owned app in AD. If so what permissions do I need to allow as the tutorial I believe doesn't cover this.

I would also like to only allow logins from my organizational AD and not a personal Microsoft account but when I set the app to a single-tenant nothing works.

here is my Github [repository](https://github.com/Grosvenorhsc/graph-tutorial)

here is a picture of my [owned app permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6IbG.png)

here is a picture of the error you get [pic of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXCKK.png)

hopefully, I have included everything that might need to help

Answer (score 0):

got this working by ensuring that I had user read permissions and mail read setting enabled on the owned permissions list and my org is still an on-prem mail system which is unable to get the calendar from this can only be done with online mail and hybrid mail servers